# Updating list with a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I want to update a list like this,

```
_list=[i for i in range(1, 6)]

for i in _list:
     _list = [j for j in _list if j**2 < 25]
     print(len(_list), i)
```

but the loop runs 5 times even though the length of the list is displayed to be 4 with every execution of the loop. Is the list variable in the for statement different from that inside the loop and if so, how do I update it?

Edit: My question seems to have been unclear to those who have answered so far, and, perhaps, to my negative marker. My code runs more along the lines of,

```
_list = [i for i in range(3, 5000, 2)]
_list.append(2)

for i in _list:
    _list = [x for x in _list if x%i != 0 or x==i]
    print(len(_list), i)
```

so I don't think I can use an if statement or a filter function, as far as I know. It's just a sieve and I want it to run just that way. I want the number of executions of the loop to be only as many as required and not more.

Comment: you keep modifying the list you are looping over inside the loop, so of course the results will be unexpected.

Comment: Don't use list as a variable name.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Sorry, I don't understand. I have just started learning programming. Can you explain more? I want to keep modifying my loop and I don't want my results to be unexpected.

Comment: @VishnuUpadhyay How do I use it, then?

Comment: @VishnuUpadhyay you edited it wrong :P

Comment: Start with this: `[i for i in range(1, 6) if i**2 < 25]`

Comment: I updated your question. use any name see https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/.

Comment: @hyades i correct it, please check.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid No, my actual code updates the list according to a condition that involves both i and j, and I made it simpler for the purpose of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is list variable in the for statement is actually different from that inside the loop. This can be verified as:

```
>>> _list = range(1,6)
>>> _list
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> id(_list)
140281026550312   # original id
>>> _list = range(1,5)  # reinitialize
>>> _list
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> id(_list)   
140281028978376   # id changed
```

As you can see re-initializing a list doesn't modify the original one as you can see `id` after re-initializing `_list` changes which means original list remains unchanged. Now the alternative to modify the original list is the `pop()` operation which can be used as:

```
>>> _list = [i for i in range(1, 6)]
>>> for i in _list:
...      popped = [_list.pop(j) for j in range(len(_list)) if not _list[j]**2 < 25] 
...      print(len(_list), i)
... 
1 1
1 2
1 3
1 4
```

Modify your 2nd code as given below to get correct output:

```
_list = [i for i in range(3, 5000, 2)] 
_list.append(2)

for i in _list:
   popped = [_list.pop(j) for j,x in enumerate(_list) if x%i==0 and x!=i] 
   # above list compression means remove all list items that are divisible by i and not equal to i
   print(len(_list), i)
```

`popped` is a dummy variable, never utilized. It is there because `pop()` operation returns popped value and these should be collected or they will be unnecessarily printed if working in interpreter mode.

Comment: I get a 'list index out of range' error in the list comprehension when elements not necessarily at the end of the list are popped out.

Comment: Can you show me the list comprehension code line on which you got an error.

Comment: _list = [_list.pop(j) for j in range(len(_list)) if i%(_list[j]) and not i == (_list[j])

Comment: Sorry it was my mistake I returned popped values to _list while actually they need to be thrown away. I've corrected my mistake with a more readable list compression for your 2nd code. Try it again..

Comment: Oh, I thought the values were popped out that way, rather than popped in. The modified code works, though I get the error back when I don't make the implicit edit you made. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Its because of you have a list comprehension inside the loop , and python calculate your desire list in first loop , so the length of list is `4` instead you can use the following code :

```
>>> l=[]
>>> for i in _list:
...     if i**2 < 25:
...      l.append(i)
...      print(len(l), i)
... 
(1, 1)
(2, 2)
(3, 3)
(4, 4)
>>> l
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Thank you, but the code in my question was a simplified version of my code, which has too many conditions for if statements to be used and involving two variable values from the list.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
l = range(1, 6)
l = filter(lambda x: x**2 < 25, _list)

print(_list) # this will print [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
_list=[i for i in range(1, 6)]  # Line 1

for i in _list:                 # Line 2
     _list = [j for j in _list if j**2 < 25]     # Line 3
     print(len(_list), i)   #Line 4
```

In Line 1 _list is initialized. The shorter way could be range(1,6), No idea why you chose list comprehension.

In Line 2 _list value is [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]. So Now you are ready for iterating 5 times.
But you are changing the _list again, with value [1, 2, 3, 4] in the first iteration itself at line No 3. So Now the Loop is going to run for 4 times, from Second Itertion of for loop in the Line 2.

Comment: So you mean that once the list is updated, the for loop starts afresh?

Comment: The for loop doesn't starts afresh, It changes the range of _list from [1,2,3,4,5] to [1,2,3,4] in the second iteration.

Answer (score 0):

The better way to do this is with the use of [filter()](http://www.u.arizona.edu/~erdmann/mse350/topics/list_comprehensions.html#filter) function. It could be done as:

```
num_list = range(1, 6)
my_list = filter(lambda x: x**2 < 25, num_list)
```

The `my_list` list will contain the numbers from `num_list` for which square is less than 25.